# Creating new columns in pandas dataframe as summed permutations of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

Hopefully this simple explanation will get across what I'm trying to do. Suppose I had a Pandas dataframe that had the following columns:

```
A B C D E
1 2 4 6 4 
3 4 1 2 3
4 7 4 1 4
```

Does anyone know a way (without doing it manually) that I could create a new set of columns within that table that sum across subsets of permutations of the columns? I've been doing some searches and not had any luck given this being a rather specific query.

For instance if I wanted all combinations of sums of subsets of 3 columns from the 5 columns - some of the additional rows might like look like:

```
ABC ACE BDE
  7   9  12
  8   7   9
 15  12  12
```

...and so in (in this case there'd be 5C3 = 10 rows - but I'm actually looking at a 7C4 example)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you sure you mean permutations? That'd create lots of duplicate columns with just different names (order does matter in permutations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `combinations` instead `permutations` and for each values of tuple sum values together:

```
from itertools import combinations

cc = list(combinations(df.columns,3))
df = pd.concat([df.loc[:, c].sum(axis=1) for c in cc], axis=1, keys=cc)
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
print (df)
   ABC  ABD  ABE  ACD  ACE  ADE  BCD  BCE  BDE  CDE
0    7    9    7   11    9   11   12   10   12   14
1    8    9   10    6    7    8    7    8    9    6
2   15   12   15    9   12    9   12   15   12    9
```

Comment: You can't reuse the `cc` generator, it will either be exhausted by the comprehension or keys. Also, I have error when running your code.

Comment: @mozway - it was not tested simplify solution.

Comment: This worked for my purposes - I was looking at a 7c4 combination (35 new columns) for a dataframe with 500,000 rows and it took 2.5s - thanks ! And thanks for the alternative options too @mozway and Marco_CH

Answer (score 1):

Or as an alternative:

```
import itertools
    
pd.DataFrame({'{}{}{}'.format(a, b, c): df[a] + df[b] + df[c] 
              for a, b, c in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 3)})
```

**Output:**

```
   ABC  ABD  ABE  ACD  ACE  ADE  BCD  BCE  BDE  CDE
0    7    9    7   11    9   11   12   10   12   14
1    8    9   10    6    7    8    7    8    9    6
2   15   12   15    9   12    9   12   15   12    9
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the underlying numpy array for efficiency.

```
from itertools import combinations

a = df.to_numpy()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([a[:,list(c)].sum(1)
                              for c in combinations(range(df.shape[1]), 3)
                              ]).T,
                   columns=map(''.join, combinations(df, 3))
                   )
```

output:

```
   ABC  ABD  ABE  ACD  ACE  ADE  BCD  BCE  BDE  CDE
0    7    9    7   11    9   11   12   10   12   14
1    8    9   10    6    7    8    7    8    9    6
2   15   12   15    9   12    9   12   15   12    9
```

*NB. This is running ~10 times faster than the other pandas-based solution.*

Answer (score 0):

Because I found it very interesting, I compared the three solutions.

---

### jezrael

```
%%timeit

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,3,4],
                  "B":[2,4,7],
                  "C":[4,1,4],
                  "D":[6,2,1],
                  "E":[4,3,4]})

cc = list(combinations(df.columns,3))
df = pd.concat([df.loc[:, c].sum(axis=1) for c in cc], axis=1, keys=cc)
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
df
```

**Result:**
`5.99 ms ± 20.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

---

### mozway

```
%%timeit

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,3,4],
                  "B":[2,4,7],
                  "C":[4,1,4],
                  "D":[6,2,1],
                  "E":[4,3,4]})
    
a = df.to_numpy()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([a[:,list(c)].sum(1)
                              for c in combinations(range(df.shape[1]), 3)
                              ]).T,
                   columns=map(''.join, combinations(df, 3))
                   )
df2
```

**Result:**
`458 µs ± 868 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

---

### Marco_CH

```
%%timeit

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,3,4],
                  "B":[2,4,7],
                  "C":[4,1,4],
                  "D":[6,2,1],
                  "E":[4,3,4]})
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'{}{}{}'.format(a, b, c): df[a] + df[b] + df[c] 
              for a, b, c in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 3)})
df
```

**Result:**
`2.25 ms ± 14.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

---

So, if performance is key, mozways solution is the best by far. If performance is not that important, then we have three different approaches for every preference :-)